# circular dependency in spring using @Autowired

Tags: spring, circular-dependency

I've been facing the problem of Circular dependency in spring.

```
Public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
   @Autowired
   private RoleService roleService;
}

Public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService{
   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;
}
```

Is there any solution to deal with this problem, But I still want to use @Autowired. Other solutions might be to wire them manually. Or by using bean awares or by using bean post processor.

Comment: Ideally services should not be injected in each other, if you need functionality to two services, they both should be injected in a controller not in each other

Comment: I know that circular dependencies indicate the bad design and they should be avoided. But in large applications sometimes it's not possible to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

> The working solution was to add default-lazy-init="true" to the
>   application config xml file

Details are [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/resolve-circular-dependency).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in my case. I'm still getting BeanCurrentlyInCreationException exception.